# License users in O365 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Might be the wrong forums for this topic but someone might have a direction to point me in...

Looking for guidance on how I can set user licenses in O365 as they are enabled or disabled in my on premise AD.

I have an ADFS 2.0 environment in place with directory sync that is handling authentication and syncing accounts from my on premise AD into Azure so O365 can use them...once they are in O365 I'm trying to figure out how I can routinely license/un license them as their status changes on premise in AD.

Any recommendations on how this could be done? I'm assuming there is some sort of PowerShell that would be involved which would have to be run each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
New-MsolUser -DisplayName "Caleb Sills" -FirstName Caleb `
-LastName Sills -UserPrincipalName calebs@contoso.onmicrosoft.com `
-Department Operations -UsageLocation US `
-LicenseAssignment contoso:ENTERPRISEPACK
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn530773.aspx
http://www.everonit.com/techtips/techtips/tech-tips-for-techs-applying-office-365-licenses-in-bulk-using-powershell/

Check user if it is already licence or not

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777380